# Template syntax for classifying abstract classes

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-class

While browsing some code I have encountered the following template:

```
template<typename T>
class is_abstract
{
    class No { };
    class Yes { No no[3]; };

    template<class U>
    static No test(U (*)[1]); // not defined

    template<class U>
    static Yes test(...); // not defined 

public:
    enum { result = (sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(Yes)) };
};
```

I understand that `test<T>(0)` will be invoked with the overload which returns `No` for non-abstract (***`is_abstract<SomeAbstractClass>::result` = true***) classes and the other overload otherwise, but why?

What is this `U (*)[1]` syntax in the method signature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test<T>(0)` will either call the first or the second overload of `test`. The second overload is quite standard (it is the fallback when the first overload is ill-formed).

Now, how to make the first declaration ill-formed for abstract class? Here are some possible solutions:

```
template<class U>
static No test(U); // (1)

template<class U>
static No test(U*); // (2)

template<class U>
static No test(U (*)[1]); // (3)
```

But there are problem with `(1)` and `(2)`:

1. You would need to call `test<T>(T())`, which would be ill-formed for any abstract class `T` (not only the declaration, but also the call), so [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) would not work (there would be no fallback since the code would be ill-formed "before" overload resolution);
2. `U*` is always valid, even for an abstract class, so this is not OK;
3. Is probably the simpler solution here since `U (*)[1]` do not require you to instantiate a `T()`  during the call but the declaration is ill-formed for abstract type so the fallback to `test(...)` works as needed.

Note that since C++11, there is a [`std::is_abstract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_abstract) class defined by the standard.

---

*Side note on `is_*` classes:*

This is probably an old implementation, there are easier way to do this now (since C++11). Also note that using `value` instead of `result` would be much better here (would follow standard convention). A C++11 implementation following the standard's convention could be<sup>1</sup>:

```
template <class T>
std::false_type is_abstract_(T (*)[1]);

template <class T>
std::true_type is_abstract_(...);

template<typename T>
struct is_abstract: decltype(is_abstract_<T>(0)) { };
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> If you need to test if a class is abstract or not, use the standard [`std::is_abstract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_abstract), but if you need to create your own `is_*` classes, you should follow this example instead of the one you found.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

`U (*)[1]` is a pointer to an array of one instance of `U`.
Since abstract classes cannot be instanciated, such an array would be ill-formed, thus the overload is ignored (that's [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)), and the call falls back to the `(...)` overload.